# CSS multiple carousel but style only attached to one

Tags: css

I'm looking to change the code below so it only runs when a certain class is attached to the carousel. I have multiple carousels on the same page.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Show 3rd slide on sm  if col-sm-6*/
    .carousel-inner .active.col-sm-6.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -50%;  /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
                    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 active">
                            <img src="assets/img/car_logos/car_logo_PNG1636.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block contain" alt="img1">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are doing this when you can do this using selector or a class?
If you need more customization / controls over a carousel item then do check the [owl  carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html).